# Excel MATCH Statement Nested in INDIRECT Statement?

Tags: excel, nested, match, excel-match

I have these two functions:

1. `=INDIRECT("A"& MATCH(A16,Sheet1!A:A,1))`
2. `=INDIRECT(J3&"!    PUT FUNCTION 1 HERE     ")`

Function 1 returns the value of cell `A17`, on Sheet 1.

Function 2 *should* return the value of `A17` on Sheet 2 (the second indirect function refers to cell `J3`, which contains "Sheet2").

When I combine the two, I receive an error message.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you wrote, function 1 returns the actual value of cell `A16`. If you nest func 1 in func 2, Excel would resolve this into:

```
=INDIRECT(J3 & "!" & Function1)
=INDIRECT(J3 & "!" & INDIRECT("A" & MATCH(A16, Sheet1!A:A, 1)))
=INDIRECT("Sheet2!My value in A16")
```

Obviously, this leads to an error.
To solve this, suppress the second `INDIRECT`:

```
=INDIRECT(J3 & "!" & "A" & MATCH(A16, Sheet1!A:A, 1))
```